# Find a substring in a dictionary; value substring of key; Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, match

Question: Find a substring

You are given a dictionary of the US states and their capitals (my actual list is larger than provided below). The keys in the dictionary are states and the values are capital names.

Write a code to return a list of all capitals that contain the name of a state in their name as a substring.

HINT: For example, Indianapolis as a capital name and Indiana as a state name is one of the key/value pairs that your code would find. Your code should add Indianapolis to the list. After you found all capitals and added them to the list, print out the list.

```
# Run this cell to create a dictionary of states' capitals

capitals={
    'Illinios': 'Springfield',
    'Indiana': 'Indianapolis',
    'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
    'Oregon': 'Salem',
}
```

I believe I have to use substring or contains. I am new to Python. I appreciate it, thank you.

```
capitals={capital:state}
list_of_all_capitals=[]
for capital in state
list_of_all_capitals.append=[capital]
print(list_of_all_capitals)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433086/find-a-substring)

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will help community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use list-comprehension that iterates over dictionary and check for the existence of substring using the membership operator:

```
[y for x, y in capitals.items() if x in y]
```

In **code**:

```
capitals = {
    'Illinios': 'Springfield',
    'Indiana': 'Indianapolis',
    'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
    'Oregon': 'Salem',
}

print([y for x, y in capitals.items() if x in y])
# ['Indianapolis', 'Oklahoma City']
```